# Using Grails Transaction when saving two different domain object in one shot

Tags: grails, spring-transactions

I have to domain classes that need to be updated at the same time, I want to use a transaction  in order to allow changes to both or neither. For example :

I have two different domain classes (User, and Follow)

```
User currentUser =..
User targetUser = ..
Follow followUser = ..

targetUser.follower = targetUser.follower + 1
currentUser.follow = currentUser.follow + 1
targetUser.save(flush:true)
currentUser.save(flush:true)
followUser.save(flush:true)
```

I want all of this happen together or if one fails none of it happen and gets rolled back. How can I do this in grails ? I saw the DomainObject.withTransaction, but I have two different domain, so should I do nested ?

Answer (score 3):

The proper solution is to move this transactional code into a Service. The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/services.html) outlines how to create and use services from your controllers. That's the proper solution.

However, that's not the only way. As you have seen there is the ability to run code within a transaction scope using withTransaction. For example (directly from the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html)):

```
Account.withTransaction { status ->
    def source = Account.get(params.from)
    def dest = Account.get(params.to)

    int amount = params.amount.toInteger()
    if (source.active) {
        source.balance -= amount

        if (dest.active) {
            dest.amount += amount
        }
        else {
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        }
    }
}
```

The code within the withTransaction closure can span any number of Domain classes. You can mix and match as you see fit.

Again, to stress. **The proper way is to use services**.